# stop searching after find first element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The answer might be very easy but i cannot find it:

I have this pipeline

```
  return (await Blog.aggregate([
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $match: { _id } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: User.collection.name,
        localField: "author",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "author"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$author"
    },
    {
      $set: {
        author: "$author.author"
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        ips: 0
      }
    }
  ]).exec())[0]
```

I have added `$limit` to 1 because i was thinking that it will stop searching for elements after finding 1. But instead the search is limited to only 1 element.

That means if there are 10 elements only the first will be scanned because of `$limit` 1.

How can i optimize this pipeline ?

Comment: it should be the second stage, not the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place $limit stage after $match stage and that should do it.